# CSS Positioning with HTML Div Images

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to create a social navigation bar with a fixed position in the top right corner of the web browser.  My goal is that the navigation bar will be displayed inline-block horizontally.  But I cannot get it to display horizontally without it somehow jumping to the opposite side of the browser.

```
        <div class="social-icons-round">
            <div class="social-icon-rnd"><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img height="34" width="34" src="file://C:\Workspace\Random\Schools\images\facebook-round.png"></a></div>
            <div class="social-icon-rnd"><a href="http://www.twitter.com"><img height="34" width="34" src="file://C:\Workspace\Random\Schools\images\twitter-round.png"></a></div>
            <div class="social-icon-rnd"><a href="http://www.google.com"><img height="34" width="34" src="file://C:\Workspace\Random\Schools\images\g+-round.ico"></a></div>
        </div><!-- end of social-icons-round -->

.social-icons-round {
    position: fixed;
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
}

.social-icons-rnd {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lose the float.  Set the "right" to how far from the right, and the "top" from how far from top.  That's all you need.

```
.social-icons-round {
    position: fixed;
    /*float: right;*/
    top:10px;
    right:20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: That should be fine.  Although, I find that inline fails on some older browsers.  Don't know why.  You might be better off putting a float left on your individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "right:0;" instead of using float.

**eg:**

```
.social-icons-round {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;            // Add this
    right:0;          // Add this
    padding: 5px;
}
```

And fix the name of the class "*social-icons-rnd*" to "*social-icon-rnd*", because you use "*social-icon-rnd*" on the div class ( without the S in the icons word ):

**You can see it working here:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGNbvp?editors=110